# Is it possible to install an AppCache manifest file while offline?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, google-chrome-app

In times where I want to install an offline Browser App in an offline setting, is it possible to install the AppCache manifest file so the app can show up at http://example.com/app.html? It doesn't matter which browser, I just need one.

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox, yes, but the process is not user-friendly, it's meant to be used by the build system when packaging built-in apps for [Gaia](http://wiki.mozilla.org/Gaia). See the [install-gaia](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/Makefile#L518) target on Gaia's Makefile and [install-gaia.py](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/build/install-gaia.py).

You can tweak the scripts to install the application cache and manifest on your Firefox profile, but it's a rather tricky process.

Comment: Hi Reuben. Thanks for the info. Firefox Marketplace apps are now installable on Android which is also kind of an answer. https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/06/firefox-os-apps-run-on-android/